# can vectorize this for-loop with update variable in each iterate?

Tags: python, numpy

Can we vectorize this for-loop that finally result update in each iterate and using the result in for like below:

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
y = np.array([1,-1,1])
z = np.array([-1,1,-1])

w = 2
out = np.array([10,20])
for xi,yi,zi in zip(x, y, z):
    out = out + (w*(yi-zi))*xi
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([ 18, 32])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
(w*(y-z)*x.T).sum(1)
```

output: `array([ 8, 12])`

Add existing array:

```
out = np.array([10,20])
out += (w*(y-z)*x.T).sum(1)
```

output: `array([18, 32])`

Comment: if out change like : [10,20]

Comment: Then perform a simple addition…

Comment: thanks for your answer , I check this is correct but I can't understand why this is correct? in the question code in each iteration `out` change but in your answer `out` one time changing?

Comment: Well, with your loop, you sum on each step, in my case I calculate all (as vector) and sum at the end. This is the exact same thing, not the same order